# Server breaking javascript file

Tags: javascript

Ok, this is really strange. I am not js proffesional so debugging this took me almost 2 hours.What happend is that I am styling one custom cms with this theme:

http://templates.tricyclelabs.com/adminica/login.php

After Ive finished with it, everything worked well on localhost.After uploading it to server, that IPhone slider didnt work. After debugging I saw that my server is breaking javascript file, everything is in one line which means if you use "//" everyting will be commented:

```
$(function() {  // Form inputs
    $("fieldset > div > input[type=text]").addClass("text");        
    $("fieldset > div > input[type=password]").addClass("text");
    $("fieldset > div > textarea").addClass("textarea");
    $("fieldset > div > input[type=checkbox]").addClass("checkbox");
    $("fieldset > div > input[type=radio]").addClass("radio");
    $("fieldset > div > input[type=checkbox].indeterminate").prop("indeterminate", true);                   
// Textxarea Autogrow
    $('textarea.autogrow').autoGrow();              
// Dismiss alert box
    $(".alert.dismissible").click(function(){               
        $(this).animate({opacity:0},'slow',function(){              
            $(this).slideUp();
        });
    });         
// Input Datepicker Config                
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd M yy' });;
// input Slider Config
    function slideMarkers(event,ui){                                      
        var totalLabels = $(this).children().children().size();         
        $(this).children("ol.slider_labels").children("li").css({               
        "margin-right":(100/(totalLabels-1))+"%"
        });
    }
    $( ".slider" ).slider({
```

You can see file here:

[breaked javascript](http://putuj.org/frog/admin/javascripts/adminica_forms.js)

The fix was to uplaod that file to my other host. Who reads it very clean,spacing enters etc...
[working version](http://dnslaktasi.com/adminica_forms.js)

So my question is, does anyone know how this happend? That my first host which is siteground.com was breaking my javascript file, and other one didnt?

Its really frustrating, especily when you lose 2 hours on this.

Comment: Are you transferring data in `ASCII` mode? do you know which is the server `OS`?

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you're looking for by what about using `/* comments */` that will work either way

Comment: Its not about comments, its that code is fully messed up, all around screen.http://dnslaktasi.com/2.jpg I am using filezille, not sure if its in ASCII mode. I think its linux OS

Comment: I found out that its actually modifying js file to be one long line, without any line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the line endings of text files differ system to system. They should be

- `\r\n` on Windows
- `\n` on Unix
- `\r` on Mac

So, if you write a text file on Windows and open it on Unix, you'll see proper line breaks (although with "garbage" `\r` symbols). Similarily on mac, proper `\r` linebreaks with garbage `\n`. However, moving between Linux and Mac will result in complete misunderstanding of linebreaks. Similarily, moving from any of them to Windows will mean insufficient symbolic for the linebreak.

All of this could lead to disregarding the linebreaks and seeing the text as a single line. Check the operating systems on both of the machines. This is the most probable cause of issue, well - unless your server does this on purpose :)